# PHP header() gives headers already sent

Tags: hooks, headers, session, init

I am working on a checkout proces in Wordpress where if customer clicks on the checkout button he gets redirected to a payment provider.

**Important to know:**

- I use a `session` in this proces.
- I use PHP `header()` function to sent the customer to this location.

**My problem:**
Now when you click the button, there is no redirect, but an error instead.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/template/header.php:24)
>   in
>   /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/template/page-checkout.php
>   on line 84

Line 84 is:

```
header( "Location: " . $payment->getPaymentUrl() );
```

So it looks like I need to do the redirect earlier, but I don't know how to do it. Has anyone any idea? Hook the `init` or `send_headers` action?

I have one solution at the moment which solves the problem, but I know that it is not the right one. The solution is placing `ob_start()` in the top of my header.php

Comment: Where is your code? Please post it in context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do it with WordPress's inbuilt redirect function; wp_redirect();

```
wp_redirect( $payment->getPaymentUrl() );
exit;
```